# touching displays and fingerprint sensors

Tags: drivers

hello everyone my laptop is hp pavillion x360 and i have fingerprint sensor and touch screen 
i am thinking of moving to ubuntu i am web developer and mobile app developer.

i want to ask about ,

1. is there any driver to operate my fingerpring sensor for authentication purpose? in windows its windows hello
2. is there any software like touch keyboard in ubuntu ? which is basically keyboard on display like phones keyboard

i looked in many websites i was only able to find github repo for fingerprint sensor but i don't think it is a trusted product which i can use and its installaion wasn't very clear

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touchscreen should work without problems and Ubuntu supplies an onscreen touch keyboard.

Regarding the fingerprint sensor, you will probably run into issues. Most probably your device will have a Validity fingerprint sensor. And there is no support from the hardware vendor for Linux. The kernel drivers are developed by the community (most notably `libfprint`).

For more details, you can check www.linux-hardware.org. Looking at the [probes Validity fingerprint sensors](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search&vendor=Validity+Sensors#list), you can see that most sensors are not supported (yet). Of course you can check your particular model in detail there as well.

[Libfprint](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint) has a issue section, you can check the development status for your particular fingerprint sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for the onscreen keyboard. There is a nice one called `onboard` you could try.